# How do I display data in horizontal orientation in JSF as repeater in Asp.Net?

Tags: java, jsf

I saw datatable component in JSF and it typically renders as table row by row. But what do I do if I want to display something not in vertical orientation but in horizontal manner? Say, suppose I want to make a photo album so I need to be able to display rows of database table in column format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make use of another [`UIData`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html) based component wherein you have full control over the output, such as [Facelets'](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) [`ui:repeat`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html), [Tomahawk's](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/) [`t:dataList`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_dataList.html) or [RichFaces'](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) [`rich:dataList`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataLists.jsf?c=dataList&tab=usage) or [`a4j:repeat`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/repeat.jsf?c=repeat&tab=usage).

E.g.

```html
<ul>
    <ui:repeat items="#{bean.photos}" var="photo">
        <li><img src="#{photo.url}" alt="#{photo.title}" /></li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

in combination with for example

```
li { 
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

The `t:dataList` and `rich:dataList` can render `<ul>` and `<li>` for you. You just have to print the `<img>` (or `h:graphicImage` if you prefer that) and apply a shot of CSS.

**Update**: as a bonus and as horizontally scrolling the page is generally bad for UX, you'd like to make it a carousel. Just style the `<ul>` element as follows then:

```
ul {
    width: 500px; /* Just pick whatever width it needs to be. */
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: none;
}
```