# Show multiple columns for data table

Tags: css, jsp, jsf, xhtml

I use a DataTable to show multiple objects that are stored in an arraylist

```
<h:dataTable value="#{commandCenter.onlineEmployees}" var="emp">

                    <h:column >
                        <div class="employee">
                            <div id="image">
                                <h:outputText value="img"></h:outputText>
                            </div>
                            <h:outputText value="#{emp.name}, #{emp.age}" />
                            <div id="name">
                                <h:outputText value="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </h:column>
```

Actually this only shows all values in one column and multiple rows. 
I want to show them in multiple columns . I couldn't find a tag like `<h:row>`, so how can I do this?

Comment: There isn't a component in plain JSF to do this. There are third party libraries that offers you a grid component i.e. [PrimeFaces `<p:dataGrid>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datagrid.jsf) and [RichFaces `<rich:dataGrid>`](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dataGrid&skin=blueSky). Otherwise, you could construct your own using a `<h:panelGrid>` and `<ui:repeat>`. Note that this comment is oriented to JSF 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I display data in horizontal orientation in JSF as repeater in Asp.Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523669/how-do-i-display-data-in-horizontal-orientation-in-jsf-as-repeater-in-asp-net)

Comment: thanks guys, I'll go with primefaces