# JSF row representation

Tags: jsf

empId empname address

123   john    US

321   Rod     UK

I want below representation in JSF 1.2 not in 2.1

with out using prime faces and t:datatable

empId     123    321

empname   john   Rod

address   US     UK

can anyone suggest me how to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523669/how-do-i-display-data-in-horizontal-orientation-in-jsf-as-repeater-in-asp-net

Comment: hey can u tell me to use UI: what is the jar that should be added in our lib

Comment: It's unsupportable in JSF 1.2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696728/iterating-over-a-list-in-jsf-1-2  
What about upgrading to newer version ?

Comment: sry..my application is containing JSF 1.2 so please tell me any other possibility  to display required input..