# How to display JSF dataTable column wise with data model in Java

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

My Requirement:
Display a JSF DataTable like the below one (Header & Patient Data columns wise)

[The data is fetched from Class PatientDetails.java which has all the variable n getter n setter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPik8.png)

Comment: For me it's totally unclear what you're asking. Do you maybe want to delete a entire column and not a row? Please improve your question. Also I doubt your questions is related to java. Only use java tag on primefaces questions if a java developer which has no clue about jsf could also help you.

Comment: Only use java tags on plain java questions (reproduceble with just a plain jdk) and please LOOK at your own question. Formating is completely lost

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523669/how-do-i-display-data-in-horizontal-orientation-in-jsf-as-repeater-in-asp-net

Comment: To rephrase, I want to print <p:dataTable> with the below layout :

Comment: So you want to display your rows horizontally and your columns vertically? Then you can't use the normal datable for that, take a look at my link, you need to use ui:repeat instead (or the new p:repeat component if you're on PF 6.0+)

Comment: @lastresort - Yeah you got my problem right...

Comment: I have now added the image to represent how i need to populate the data..

Comment: @lastresort - Since i am novice, I am unable to understand the logic behind your link... Can you help me out with relevant p:repeat code & java data object type to get this implemented ?